# C++ removing certain symbol/punctuation

Tags: c++, punctuation, remove-if

`token.erase(std::remove_if(token.begin(), token.end(), ispunct), token.end());`

It seems that using `ispunct` will remove all punctuation. Is it possible to only remove certain types? For example if I want to remove all punctuation except, for example colon? Or do you have to write your own condition in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) *(or a callable object)* as the predicate of your `token.erase(...)` call:

```
token.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        token.begin(), 
        token.end(), 
        [](char x){ return ispunct(x) && x != ':'; }), 
    token.end());
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem in a very efficient way!